# java applet slow on window 7 (64bit) machine

Tags: java, applet

I am running java applet on windows 7 64bit (firefox 39.0). It take 10 second to load(showing java process icon meanwhile ) where as it take 1 second to run on window 8 64bit machine(firefox 39.0). it's also fine on 32(bit) window 7.

Why it is slow on window 7(64bit).

Comment: Are you using proxy? Try Firefox 41  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1165286

Comment: @zakki yes i am using proxy...